merge sort using react for random number data
I am trying to learn React by following the below video.
For some reason nothing printing inside div tag.
can you let me know how to fix it.
Providing the code and sandbox below.
I debugged by putting console but still no luck
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFXYym4Wbkc&list=PL3lfepputJuGAaI3S7FvcBIutzHNtZ_pb&index=1
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/l4q4pz?file=%2Fsrc%2FsortingVisualizer%2FsortingVisualizer.jsx%3A1%2C1-37%2C1
import React from "react";

const number_of_array_bars = 310;

const sortingVisualizer = () => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {}, []);
  const resetArray = () => {
    const newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < number_of_array_bars; i++) {
      newArray.push(randomIntFromInterval(5, 730));
    }
    console.log("newArray", newArray);
    setArray(newArray);
  };
  const render = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {console.log("array", array)}
        {array.map((value, index) => {
          <div key={index} style={{ height: "${value}px" }}>
            test
          </div>;
        })}
      </>
    );
  };
  return render();
};

export default sortingVisualizer;

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}


The codesandbox link you shared appears to be private, can you make it public?

Looks like you meant to call resetArray once on first render, but useEffect only runs an empty function. Try changing that line to useEffect(resetArray, []) and either move it below where you assign a function to resetArray or change that assignment to a hoisted function declaration, like function resetArray() {...}.

@asportnoy I made it public, can you help me    https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/l4q4pz?file=%2Fsrc%2FsortingVisualizer%2FsortingVisualizer.jsx%3A10%2C3

@Jason T Szabo thanks for response, I made the changes but still I don't see the console  https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/l4q4pz?file=%2Fsrc%2FsortingVisualizer%2FsortingVisualizer.jsx%3A10%2C3

Fixed up here - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sorting-forked-283ztp?file=%2Fsrc%2FsortingVisualizer%2FsortingVisualizer.jsx%3A23%2C39. There were several other problems which were pointed out in the console

The following are the two reasons for not getting the output.
Note : The logical issues if any with merge sorting in the code given have not been addressed by the following answer.
a) If the body of the function is an expression, then there must not be the pair of curly braces and the semicolon.
array.map((value, index) => {
          <div key={index} style={{ height: "${value}px" }}>
            test
          </div>;
        })

Corrected to this:
array.map((value, index) => 
          <div key={index} style={{ height: "${value}px" }}>
            test
          </div>
        )

b) useEffect has been invoked with en empty code handler.
 useEffect(() => {}, []);

Corrected to this:
  useEffect(() => resetArray, []);

Corrected code - full listing
   import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    export default function App() {
      return <>{sortingVisualizer()}</>;
    }
    
    const number_of_array_bars = 310;
    
    const sortingVisualizer = () => {
      const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
    
      const resetArray = () => {
        const newArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < number_of_array_bars; i++) {
          newArray.push(randomIntFromInterval(5, 730));
        }
        console.log('newArray', newArray);
        setArray(newArray);
      };
      const render = () => {
        return (
          <>
            {console.log('array', array)}
            {array.map((value, index) => {
              return (
                <div key={index} style={{ height: '${value}px' }}>
                  {value}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </>
        );
      };
      useEffect(() => resetArray, []);
      return render();
    };
    
    function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

